# How do I use file handling to add create a txt file which saves the score of the player in a simple number guessing game on python?

Tags: python, file-handling

So basically I have this number guessing game for my school project-

```
import random
import math

lower = int(input("Enter Lower bound:- "))

upper = int(input("Enter Upper bound:- "))

x = random.randint(lower, upper)

def num_of_chances(U,L):
    return round(math.log(U - L + 1, 2))

print("You've only ",num_of_chances(upper,lower)," chances to guess the integer!")
count = 0

while count < num_of_chances(upper,lower):
    count += 1

    guess = int(input("\nGuess a number:- "))

    if x == guess:
        print("\nCongratulations you did it in ",count, " try")
        break
    elif x > guess:
        print("You guessed too small!")
    elif x < guess:
        print("You Guessed too high!")

if count >= math.log(upper - lower + 1, 2):
    print("\nThe number is %d"% x)
    print("\tBetter Luck Next time!")
```

I had to somehow implement file handling into this code, so I though about doing something which allows the user to play multiple times and keep track of their wins/ losses and to save the username (which will have to ask for) and the wins/ losses in a file and allow the user to view the leaderboard pulled from that file.
Thing is the codes based on file handling which I have practiced were way simpler than this, and I do not really understand how do I go about to approach this. I have the deadline in 2 hours, and I have absolutely no idea what to do right now(I wasn't slacking off before this, I actually was studying the entire time for an extremely competitive entrance exam).

Please suggest me the approach that I should go about to code this, keeping it as simple as possible, and also if possible write the code, I'll be more than grateful !

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to do the filehandling; do you want to have it in a .txt file for each user, do you want a .csv file, are you allowed to use other libraries for the file-handling (e.g pandas). You write ".txt" file in the title, but do not mention if it *has* to be a .txt file in the question.

You can create a simple .csv file with the structure

```
#user_stats.csv
username,wins,loss
```

eg.

```
#user_stats.csv
user,wins,loss
user1,5,10
user2,3,100
user3,0,1
```

which you read/write using `pandas.read_csv` ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)) or `df.to_csv("user_stats.csv",index=False")` ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)).

Then you just load that in the beginning:

```py
username = input("Enter username:")
df_stats = pd.read_csv("user_stats.csv") #load stats
df_stats = df_stats.loc[df_stats["user"]==username] #Get user with the provided username (if exists)
.
.
.
```

Then you can just increment `df_stats["wins"]` by 1 if they win or the loss by 1 if they loose.

Make sure to handle the difference between a new user and when the username is incorrect when you load the `user_stats` at the beginning (if you want to)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I actually found out using the json module makes the code simpler cuz it allows data in the form of dictonary

Comment: Correct, it does. You didn't specify how you would like the format